# Scan wifi and display them in a list - android

Tags: android, wifi

these two classes scan wifi for anyone needing code, I used them in my application and it works well. It displays wifi scans in a listview. 
ListAdapterWifi.java

```
public class ListAdapterWifi extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;


    public ListAdapterWifi(Context context, List<ScanResult> wifiList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.wifiList = wifiList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return wifiList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        System.out.println("viewpos" + position);
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listeadapter, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.tvDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvDetails.setText("SSID :: " + wifiList.get(position).SSID
                + "\nForce du signal reçu :: " + wifiList.get(position).level
                + "\n@ mac du point d'accès :: " + wifiList.get(position).BSSID
                + "\nCanal :: "
                + convertFrequencyToChannel(wifiList.get(position).frequency)
                + "\nFréquence :: " + wifiList.get(position).frequency
                + "\nType de sécurité :: " + wifiList.get(position).capabilities);

        return view;
    }


    public static int convertFrequencyToChannel(int freq) {
        if (freq >= 2412 && freq <= 2484) {
            return (freq - 2412) / 5 + 1;
        } else if (freq >= 5170 && freq <= 5825) {
            return (freq - 5170) / 5 + 34;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView tvDetails;

    }


}
```

WifiMonitorActivity.java

```
public class WifiMonitorActivity extends Activity {
private WifiManager mainWifi;
private WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
private Button btnRefresh;
ListAdapterWifi adapter;
ListView lvWifiDetails;
public List<ScanResult> wifiList;
WifiManager wifi;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.wifiresult );

 lvWifiDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWifiDetails);
 btnRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
 mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();

 registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
 WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
 scanWifiList();

btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 scanWifiList();
  }
  });

}

private void setAdapter() {
 adapter = new ListAdapterWifi(getApplicationContext(), wifiList);
 lvWifiDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
}
private void scanWifiList() {

 mainWifi.startScan();
 wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
 setAdapter();

}

protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}


protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
    super.onPause();
}


class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {   
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to add add `default: System.out.println(wifiList.get(i).BSSID);` at the end of the switch statement and see the result, it may give you a clue.

Comment: That means the switch statement is not being executed at all, probably the whole click listener is not being activated either.  what is "**maposition**"? Can you show us its declaration?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was out. I feel that the problem is something silly, You already have done the hard part.Your button declaration should be something like `**Button maposition = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mapositionID);**`. Can you also post your XML file?

Comment: No.  I did the declaration.  You know what i did wrong is the if condition, i replaced the = by equals

Comment: Great! No one noticed that, I guess its because the code posted was a little too much. By the way try also to use the debugger next time( if you already are not using it), it helps to narrow down and isolate the problem. Well, have a good luck in your project.

Comment: Thank you Addis :)